# Cannot POST base64 image content over http to PHP server

Tags: php, ios, swift

I have read all the other threads but my problem is a mix of those. So I am trying to send some content over to a php server through HTTP in swift. Everything works fine until I append an image base64 content to the body of the http tag. I checked the php backend max post size, wasnt it. I copy pasted the image content that was generated in swift and pasted it in chrome and image was there, so image is not faulty.

This is the sample code of what I have
let url = NSURL(string: "https:example.com/endpoint")
        //        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession();

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

    var body = "csrf_token=" + (token.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())! as String)
    body += "&email=" + (email?.text)!
    body += "&first_name=" + (firstName?.text)!
    body += "&last_name=" + (lastName?.text)!
    body += "&password=" + password!.text!
    //body += "&image_content=" + imageContent
    body += "&confirm_password=" + confirmPassword!.text!
    body += "&provider=" + provider
    body += "&pictureURL=" + pictureURL

    request.HTTPBody = body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.addValue("https:example.com/", forHTTPHeaderField: "origin")
    request.addValue("https:example.com/endpoint", forHTTPHeaderField: "referrer")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (
        let data, let response, let error) in
        guard let _:NSData = data,  let _:NSURLResponse = response where error == nil else {
            print("error")
            print(data)
            print(response)
            return;
        }
        let dataString = NSString(data :data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        print(dataString)

        if ((response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode == 200) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginAfterSignup", sender: nil)
            })
        }
        else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                print((response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
                print("error code, could not sign up and login")
            })
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

So when I uncomment the line with the base64 string content, I go to the throwback call and it prints the "error".
I have no clue why its not sent through http. Is there a rule I have to obey? Do I have to set a certain http header once I append a large string? Am I missing something here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it was a stupid Apache settings error. I have previously modified max_post_size and got nothing. However this time I modified the max request body parameter and I could finally send data to the server.